# What is the complement of "since"?

Tags: phrase-request, prepositions

I want to say that a certain fact is true "from the beginning of the story to the present".

But AFAIK, the preposition "from" is not so good for describing time, and I should use the preposition "since" instead. So, maybe I should say: "**since** the beginning of the story to the present". But this sounds wrong.

So maybe "**since** the beginning of the story **until** the present"? This sounds awkward.

What is the best way to say this?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with *from ... to ...". But wait for second opinions.

Comment: related: [Is there a difference in meaning between “from the beginning” and “since the beginning”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/26078/16833)

Comment: I agree, there's nothing inherently wrong with using "from/to" when describing a time and the original sentence reads just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since *since* marks a point in time and not a timespan, you have to construct your sentence in a certain way.

> That fact **has been true** *since* the beginning of the story.

If you want to emphasize that the trueness is inverted right now (I could have said "It's not true anymore") I'd suggest something along the lines of

> It has been true up until now

Comment: So, you say I should not try to complement "since" with "to", "until" etc.?

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi "from .. to" marks a timespan, so does "since .. until", you might not mix them. My second example could be rewritten as "Since the beginning it has been true, up until now"